# How to get file size in WinRT?

Tags: c#, filesize, winrt-async

In WinRT there is no `FileInfo` class, only a `StorageFile` class.

How can I get the size of a file using the `StorageFile` class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So here you go:

```
storageFile.getBasicPropertiesAsync().then(
    function (basicProperties) {
        var size  = basicProperties.size;
    }
);
```

Comment: capital G on GetBasicPropertiesAsync for what its worth.

Answer (score 11):

In C#:

```
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
BasicProperties pro = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
if (pro.Size != 0){}
```

You should using Windows.Storage.FileProperties for BasicProperties.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
        create_task(file->GetBasicPropertiesAsync()).then([this, file](BasicProperties^ basicProperties)
        {
            String^ dateModifiedString = dateFormat->Format(basicProperties->DateModified) + " " + timeFormat->Format(basicProperties->DateModified);
            OutputTextBlock->Text += "\nFile size: " + basicProperties->Size.ToString() + " bytes" + "\nDate modified: " + dateModifiedString;

        });
```

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.basicproperties.size.aspx

Comment: He needs the answer in [tag:c#], not C++

Comment: :)) finally made it! I'm so new here :D